# ListView and DB Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview, phpmyadmin

I have and issue with an Android App.

Basically the app have two main points. It has to be updated from a DB and I need to display a ListView in this ListView every item is an entry in the DB, and should have his own Layout.

The DB is needed to be updated by a non-programmer user. So I have been looking for information before asking here.
I have seen that you can use a PhpMyAdmin Db in Android. That solves the issue about a non-programmer user updating the app.

That left two points:

1º How to use the ListView (Or other method) to display a template from the DB entrys

2º How can I update an App without making it download from the Play Store or similar?

Thanks, and sorry for the issue.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database. *You* could use it to manipulate your database, but should not expose it to the users. Instead, you should write some custom code that displays a nice interface to the user and does the work of interacting with the database. Also, phpMyAdmin requires a web browser to work on the client and a server with a webserver, working PHP interpreter, and direct access to the MySQL server, so you could install phpMyAdmin on your own publicly available server but it's unlikely for you to run it directly on each user's individual phones.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically display items from DB in ListView in separate layouts you need custom adapter. Create custom adapter class and read your DB in it, adding new ListView items. Attach this adapter to your ListView by calling ListView.setAdapter().

Comment: Or simply use a ListAdapter after you recover the list from your DB ;)